# Compile time type detection of parameter types

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I do know several methods to detect whether a given class has a function with a specified signature. What I would like though is to deduce the signature at compile-time. Consider:

```
struct test_class
{
    void test( int a );
    void test( float b );
};
```

I can use decltype and SFINAE to detect the presence of a specified test() with simple syntax like `has_test<test_class,int>();`. What I would want however is something like `test_types<test_class>::types -> mpl::list< int, float >`. Anyone has a sane idea how to do that? The requirement is that the list of detectable types cannot be prepared (so it'll detect any `test( T )`, not just the ones we "register".

Comment: Don't think that's possible. What if the class has `template<class T> void test(T)`?

Comment: Then I don't care about it - it can fail, it can stack overflow. I'm only interested in the non-template functions. But you're right in the fact that it may hint on the impossibility of the task :P

Comment: is there any restriction on the argument types (int,float,...) ? or they can be literally *any* type ? can you change test() signature to something functionally equivalent ?

Comment: Any type. I can do that very simply if I would have a mpl::list<PossibleTypes>, but doing it without it seems impossible? What do you mean by functionally equivalent? Probably not though.

Comment: you don't need the list of types, it would suffice having a total order on the set of allowed types ... so I asked

Comment: by "functionally equivalent" I mean decorating the parameter type with some kind of wrapper, something like "void test(param<int,0>)", that would make it possible IIRC... or maybe by adding a default dummy parameter "void test(int,param<0> ={})" ...

Comment: Total order could be achieved by a constexpr version of typeid(), but an 0..x ordered list not so much. Decorating the parameter is a cost I might be willing to take, as long as it doesn't require me to predeclare all possible types. Ergo, I'm interested in the solution you're thinking about :)

Comment: Decorating the parameters could work, but then `using test_types = std::tuple<int, float>` inside `test_class` would work just as well.

Comment: @n.m. I know how to go from there, but I want to explicitly avoid that :)

Comment: You need to do additional work inside `test_class` to make the types discoverable, one way or another. The problem with parameter decoration is that it's all too easy to forget that your goal is to make the types discoverable, not to make SFINAE work.

Comment: In the use case, the variable parameter is from a set of structs that I could decorate, I just don't want to list them at compile time -- so parameter decoration could be done on the types themselves.

Comment: You can register each type right after it's defined/declared with a simple macro (yes I know), then go over the list of registered types and check one by one whether the corresponding function exists. That would be the easiest "decoration".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford decorating `test()` overloads in a way equivalent to (it's ugly I know, maybe you can come out with something prettier):

```
struct test_class
{
    param<int> test( int a, param_id<0> ={} );
    param<float> test( float a, param_id<1> ={} );
};
```

then something like this should work ([godbolt conformance view](https://godbolt.org/g/jXAx9P)):

```
template<typename T> struct param{ using type = T; };
template<int I> struct param_id{};
template<typename... T> struct type_list{};

struct anything{ template<typename T> operator T&&(); };

template<int I>
struct matcher
{
  template<typename T, typename E = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,param_id<I>>::value> >
  operator T();
};

template<typename T,int I,typename = std::void_t<>,typename... Ts>
struct test_types_impl{ using type = type_list<Ts...>; };

template<typename T,int I,typename... Ts>
struct test_types_impl<T,I,std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().test( anything{}, matcher<I>{} ))>,Ts...>:
  test_types_impl<T,I+1,void,Ts...,typename decltype(std::declval<T>().test( anything{}, matcher<I>{} ))::type>
{
};

template<typename T>
struct test_types{ using type = typename test_types_impl<T,0>::type; };

struct test_class
{
    param<int> test( int a, param_id<0> ={} );
    param<float> test( float a, param_id<1> ={} );
};

static_assert( std::is_same_v<test_types<test_class>::type, type_list<int,float>> );
```

the above requires at least move-constructible argument types and C++17 (but it I think it can be made to work in C++11 as well, and with any type).

`param_id` may be omitted if you manage to get a total ordering on the set of allowed parameter types. Maybe, we can even omit the `param<T>` somehow, not sure though (waiting OP feedback for this :))

Comment: This is interesting, I'll play around with it a bit!

Comment: I managed to get it down to the plain syntax I wanted, using two type "traits" -- unfortunately they need to be ordered and there are two of them - I'll think about it more, maybe I'll come up with something - https://godbolt.org/g/eC6HX7 - that anything{} tip was golden though!

Comment: The question now is - I have a compile-time hash value for every type - how can I use it instead of indices?

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz if the type<->id map is bijective and the set of all used types is not too big, you may iterate from 0 to some max value, dropping non-matchings ...

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want apply some checks for class to list of types and accumulate(?) results. If so, you can use code, like this:

```
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pop_front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/empty.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/front.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ClassT, typename ParamT>
struct check : public std::true_type
{
};

// template <typename ClassT>
// struct check<ClassT, double> : public std::false_type
// {
// };

template <typename ClassT, typename ParamList, bool list_empty>
struct apply;

template <typename ClassT, typename ParamList>
struct apply <ClassT, ParamList, true> : public std::true_type{};

template <typename ClassT, typename ParamList>
struct apply <ClassT, ParamList, false> :
public std::integral_constant<
    bool,
    apply<
            ClassT,
            typename boost::mpl::pop_front<ParamList>::type,
            boost::mpl::empty<typename boost::mpl::pop_front<ParamList>::type>::value
        >::value && check<ClassT, typename boost::mpl::front<ParamList>::type>::value>
{
};

class Test
{
};

#include <iostream>
int main(int , char ** ) {

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << apply<Test, boost::mpl::list<int, float, double>, false>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Assume, `check` is your custom check, that gave `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`. If you uncomment specialization for `double`, result will changes from `true` to `false`.

Comment: A different test type may be introduced in a DLL, so I cannot accumulate anything.

Comment: Scratch that - I realized that the list may be just for detection, and not usage later. Good point.